# Bead on a rod fixed at its center

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

I had an exam problem that I couldn’t figure out, wondering how to solve it.[image: rod and bead problem]

My issue here is I don’t know how to treat the mass and the rod. If I separate them out, how would I write a force diagram for them? Perhaps for the rod, I need to calculate the new center of mass, while for the bead the FBD is just the force of gravity pointing down?

The second part of the problem asked to solve the problem using Lagrangian mechanics and determine the equations of motion for all times t. Again, do I have two Lagrangians, one for the rod and one for the mass, or one that combined the two?

I am not asking for a full solution, but if someone could give me an accurate force body diagram or explain the initial equations that I should use for either problem, it would be much appreciated.

My attempt:

For the mechanics part, my naive answer is:

$$I=\frac{1}{12}ML^2+mr_0^2$$

Then, taking $\tau = I\cdot\alpha$,

$$\alpha = \frac{mgr_0}{(1/12ML^2+mr_0^2)}$$.

Comment: Isn't the rod exerting a force on the bead at time zero?

Comment: Normal force upwards on the bead, I guess?

Comment: Few here will want to risk neck injury by trying to read your photo!

Comment: Fixed the picture orientation.

Comment: In your attempt, you omitted the moment on the rod.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Choose inertial coordinate frame $O\, \hat{x}\hat{y}\hat{z}$, whose center $O$ is at the rod's center of mass, the unit vector $\hat{x}$ is horizontal (i.e. perpendicular to the constant force of gravity), the unit vector $\hat{y}$ is vertical (i.e. aligned with the constant gravity vector, but opposite in direction),  and the unit vector $\hat{z}$ is perpendicular to the $O\hat{x}\hat{y}-$plane. By $\vec{r} = x \, \hat{x} + y \, \hat{y} + z \, \hat{z}$ define the position vector of the bead, where the real numbers $x,y,z$ are the coordinates of the bead with respect to the frame $O\, \hat{x}\hat{y}\hat{z}$. Denote by $r = |\vec{r}|$ the distance between the origin $O$ and the bead.

I am going to look at the system bead on a rod from the most general point of view, so for now I am not going to assume more than the fact that the rod's center of mass is fixed.

Let $I=I(t)$ be inertia tensor of the rod with the bead (it changes with time because with time the rod changes its position in space and the bead changes its position on the rod, so the mass distribution and the inertia tensor should be changing too).

From Newtonian mechanics, the equations of motion are: the derivative of the angular momentum $I\,\vec{\omega}$ of the system equals the torque created by the force of gravity $-\, mg\, \hat{y}$ in this case (the only force present), i.e.

$$\frac{d}{dt}\big(I\,\vec{\omega}\big) = \vec{r} \times (-\,mg\, \hat{y}) = -\,mg \,\big(\vec{r} \times \hat{y}\big)$$

The linear velocity of the bead is $$\vec{v} = \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt} =\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}$$ so its linear acceleration should be

$$\vec{a} = \frac{d\vec{v}}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt}\big(\vec{\omega} \times \vec{r}\big)
= \frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt} \times \vec{r} + \vec{\omega} \times \frac{d\vec{r}}{dt}
= \frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt} \times \vec{r} + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{v}$$

Expand the equations of motion
$$\frac{d}{dt}\big(I\,\vec{\omega}\big) = \frac{d I}{dt} \vec{\omega} + I \frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt} = -\,mg \,\big(\vec{r} \times \hat{y}\big)$$
and express the derivative of the angular velocity
$$I \frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt} = -\, \left(\,\frac{d I}{dt} \vec{\omega} + mg \,\big(\vec{r} \times \hat{y}\big) \,\right)$$ Therefore, we have the following two important vector equations
\begin{align}
\vec{a} 
&= \frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt} \times \vec{r} + \vec{\omega} \times \vec{v}\\
I \frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt} &= -\, \left(\,\frac{d I}{dt} \vec{\omega} + mg \,\big(\vec{r} \times \hat{y}\big) \,\right)
\end{align}
Next, we simplify these two general formulas by applying the assumptions of the problem.
First, I am going to assume that the rod and the bead move only in the $O\hat{x}\hat{y}-$plane. Therefore $\vec{\omega} = \omega\, \hat{z}$ and therefore 
$$I\, \vec{\omega} = I\,\omega\, \hat{z}$$ where $I$ is just the scalar 
$$I = \frac{ML^2}{12} + mr^2$$

Second, we are looking for the linear acceleration $\vec{a} = \vec{a}(t)$ when $t=0$. It is assumed that at $t=0$ the position vector is $\vec{r} = r_0 \, \hat{x}$ (the rod is horizontal) and $\vec{v} = \vec{0}$ because at $t=0$ the system is at rest.  Therefore, $\vec{v} = \vec{0} = \vec{\omega}\times \vec{r}$ if and only if $\vec{\omega} = \vec{0}$ (i.e. no linear velocity, no angular velocity).

Thus the pair of vector equations above simplify to 
\begin{align}
\vec{a} &= \frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt} \times \vec{r}\\
\frac{d\vec{\omega}}{dt} &= -\,\frac{mg}{I}\, \big(\vec{r} \times \hat{y}\big) 
\end{align}
and so plug the second equation in the first
$$\vec{a} = -\,\frac{mg}{I}\, \big(\vec{r} \times \hat{y}\big) \times \vec{r}$$ Finally, use the fact that at $t=0$ the position of the bead is $\vec{r} = r_0\, \hat{x}$
\begin{align}
\vec{a} &= -\,\frac{mg}{I}\, \big(\vec{r} \times \hat{y}\big) \times \vec{r} \\
&=  -\,\frac{mg}{I}\, \big((r_0\, \hat{x}) \times \hat{y}\big) \times (r_0\, \hat{x})\\
&= -\,\frac{mgr_0^2}{I}\, \big( \hat{x} \times \hat{y}\big) \times \hat{x}\\
&= -\,\frac{mgr_0^2}{I}\, \hat{y}
\end{align}
because $\hat{x} \times \hat{y} = \hat{z}$ and $\hat{z} \times \hat{x} = \hat{y}$. Therefore the linear acceleration of the bead at time $t=0$ under the assumptions provided in the problem is 
$$\vec{a} = - \,\frac{mg\, r_0^2}{\left(\,\frac{ML^2}{12} + mr_0^2\,\right)}\, \hat{y}$$

Lagrangian mechanics makes things a bit more rule friendly. Basically:

1. Fix an inertial coordinate frame.
2. Take all objects in the mechanical system and write a Lagrangian for each of them as if they were alone.
3. After that sum the Lagrangians.
4. Finally, impose the constraints (the constraints transfer interactions) and if relevant, use appropriate curvilinear coordinates that parametrize these constraints.

Let's see how it works here:

1. Choose coordinate frame $O\, \hat{x}\hat{y}\hat{z}$, whose center $O$ is at the rod's center of mass, the unit vector $\hat{x}$ is horizontal (i.e. perpendicular to the constant force of gravity), the unit vector $\hat{y}$ is vertical (i.e. aligned with the constant gravity vector, but opposite in direction),  and the unit vector $\hat{z}$ is perpendicular to the $O\hat{x}\hat{y}-$plane.
2. In this case you have a rod and a bead. The rod has a fixed center $O$. Therefore, it's Lagrangian is
   $$L_{rod} = \frac{I}{2}\omega^2 = \frac{ML^2}{24} \omega^2$$ where $\omega\, \hat{z}$ is the rod's angular velocity. I have assumed that the rod is restricted to move only in the $O\hat{x}\hat{y}-$plane. 
   The Lagrangian for the bead is 
   $$L_{bead} = \frac{m}{2}\Big(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2\Big) - mgy$$
3. The Lagrangian for the system is 
   $$L = L_{rod} + L_{bead} = \frac{ML^2}{24} \omega^2 + \frac{m}{2}\Big(\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2\Big) - mgy$$
4. The constraint in this problem is that the bead always lies on the rod, sliding on it without friction. So the position of the rod and the bead are intertwined and can be parametrized using cylindrical coordinates, which are the same as polar coordinates in the $O\hat{x}\hat{y}-$plane
   \begin{align}
   x = r\, \cos{\theta}\\
   y = r\, \sin{\theta}
   \end{align} and $\omega = \dot{\theta}$. In these coordinates the rod's position is described by the angle $\theta$ from the $O\hat{x}$ axis and the constraint tells us that this same angle is the angle that the bead's position forms with the $O\hat{x}$ axis. The quantity $r$ describes how far is the bead from the center of the rod (and it can be negative). The time derivatives are
   \begin{align}
   \dot{x} = \dot{r}\, \cos{\theta} - r \dot{\theta} \sin{\theta}\\
   \dot{y} = \dot{r}\, \sin{\theta} + r \dot{\theta} \cos{\theta}
   \end{align} and so 
   $$\dot{x}^2 + \dot{y}^2 = \dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2$$
   The Lagrangian is
   $$L = \frac{ML^2}{24} \dot{\theta}^2 + \frac{m}{2}\Big(\dot{r}^2 + r^2 \dot{\theta}^2\Big) - mg\,r\sin{\theta}$$

The Euler-Lagrange equations are
\begin{align}
&\frac{d}{dt}\left(\, \frac{ML^2}{12} \,\frac{d\theta}{dt} + m\, r^2 \,\frac{d\theta}{dt}\,\right) =  -\, mg\,r\,\cos{\theta}\\
&\frac{d}{dt}\left(\, m \,\frac{d r}{dt} \,\right) = m\, r \,\left(\frac{d \theta}{dt}\right)^2 - \,mg\,\sin{\theta}
\end{align}
and can be re-expressed as
\begin{align}
\left(\, \frac{ML^2}{12} + m\, r^2\,\right) \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2} &=  - \, 2m \, r\, \frac{dr}{dt}\frac{d\theta}{dt}-\, mg\,r\,\cos{\theta}\\
\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}  &=  r \,\left(\frac{d \theta}{dt}\right)^2 - \, g\,\sin{\theta}
\end{align}